# how to prevent hack license

Tags: android, licensing, android-lvl, copy-protection

I'm developing an app, and I have integrated the license verification library to control my app. But I've noticed that rooted phones can crack the license of the app with the app Lucky Patcher. Is there any way to protect apps from this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple ways but none are secure 100%. You can use :

- Obfuscation
- Modifying the licensing system given by google
- Make your application tamper-resistant
- Offload license validation to a trusted server works very well if you have mandatory stuff to load from him (assets or data). Only one that is secure.

You can find a lot here : [Securing android lvl applications](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html)

Even if you protect your app from the automatic "[lucky app patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445598/lucky-patcher-how-can-i-protect-from-it)" keep in mind that a hacker can easily remove this check too by hand. (Wondering why it's not automatically done already checking the `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` and removing it).