# Error comparing APK Signature with original Signature

Tags: android

I am trying to compare Signature verification of my APK at run time with the original Signature key "The same one!", I follow that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14740405/4043944) so it's mustn't kill my app because it's the same one!, but it's kills the app as it's not the same one and show the toast.

That's the code

```
public void checkSignature(final Context context) {
    try {
        signatures = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

        if (signatures[0].toString() != SIGNATURE_KEY) {
            // Kill the process without warning. If someone changed the certificate
            // is better not to give a hint about why the app stopped working
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
        // Must never fail, so if it does, means someone played with the apk, so kill the process
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

    }
}
```

I used that code to get the Signature code at runtime more than time and every time gives me the same! "it's happens when i tap on button"

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Release", signatures[0].toCharsString());
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

So What's wrong with that code makes the comparing process not working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You compare strings with using != operator. This compares strings as links, not objects. You should use .equals(). 
Edited:
Also for properly compare signatures :

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
md.update(signatures[0].toByteArray());
String signature = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
if (!signature.equals(SIGNATURE_KEY)){
    //do your logic
}
```

Comment: `.equals()` only available from SDK 19 and above and my mine sdk is 10 & actually i try it and still have the problem.

Comment: What? .equals() is a default method of Object java class. Have you tried !signatures[0].toString().equals(SIGNATURE_KEY)  ? (As i understand SIGNATURE_KEY is your String constant with hash key)

Comment: Actually i used another one, but yours still not working, and yes it's my key in constant.

Comment: Same error still present! i think the problem in that line but don't know how! `signatures = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;`