# Protect in-app payment from Lucky Patcher

Tags: android, payment

I'm building an Android app which will use in-app payments and I'm interested in a way of preventing users to get free coins by using Lucky Patcher. Is there any way? 
I'm also considering using Braintree API and I'm not sure if that's safe.

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445598/lucky-patcher-how-can-i-protect-from-it

Comment: @global_warming i've read those and the signature one sounded nice, but apparently they have already bypassed that

Comment: if you are storing everything on device than you better think about those users who don't use lucky patcher.

Comment: @global_warming nothing will be stored on the device, except for cached images maybe, prices and other stuff are fetched from the server